# How to view revision number(s) of files in a folder based on comment in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am trying to find all the revision numbers that matches a specific SVN comment. Is there a way to do that?

I tried the below commands but I couldn't figure out a way to get revision. The below command just returns the commit comment

```
svn log -v sitesearch | grep 1712

[1712] testing
[1712] test
[1712] testing again
```

I tried the below command but I am not sure how to filter by comments because adding grep 1712 is not passing the revision number to next pipe.

```
svn -v log sitecode/ | grep "^r[0-9]\+ | " | cut -d' ' -f1 | cut -c2- > revisions.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward, one line command.
I still find SVN logs difficult to parse to fetch some data.

What you can do is, get the SVN logs in XML format and parse the xml in required format.

Something like this :

$ svn log --xml $SVN_URL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="27">
<author>xyz</author>
<date>2017-10-28T08:22:08.015421Z</date>
<msg>acb edee</msg>
</logentry>
<logentry
   revision="26">
<author>xyz</author>
<date>2017-10-28T07:30:51.364881Z</date>
<msg>abcdef</msg>
</logentry>
```

Now, though not pretty, even without XML parser, you can get revision ID and messages

```
svn log --xml <SVN URL> | grep -E 'revision|msg' | sed 's/revision="//g' | sed 's/">//g' | sed 's/<msg>//g' | sed 's/<\/msg>//g'
```

something like this :

```
   27
acb edee
   26
abcdef
   25
ab
```

Now, you'll need to execute some action again to make it well-formed or as per output format requirement